# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{kx^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=e^x$?

Tags: probability

I have that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{kx^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} =\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}(xe^x)=e^x(x+1)$$

But in the correction they wrote

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{kx^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=e^x.$$

I'm I wrong ?

This come from the computation of the variance of $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$:

$$\text{Var}(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}=\lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=...$$

Comment: You are not wrong.

Comment: If I would be true, the variance of an random voriable that follow a low $poisson(\lambda)$ would be $\lambda(\lambda+1)$, but it's $\lambda$, therefore it must have a mistakes somewhere.

Comment: The variance is $E(X^2) - E(X)^2$, not $E(X^2)$. The manipulation of the power series is correct, but the last formula isn't.

Comment: nice, thanks :-) Which last formula are you talking about ?

Comment: The last line. You forgot the $E(X)^2$ term.

Comment: For their claim $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{kx^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=e^x.$, make the substitution $u = k-1$ to see that they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Infinite series for the Poisson mean and variance**

This is really a Comment that won't fit into comment format.

It seems as if you can handle the calculus. To illustrate
the previous comments, here are
numerical verifications for a specific case.

Some computations (also illustrating near convergence for 100 terms, or fewer):

```
 k = 1:100;  x = 5
 sum(k*x^(k-1)/factorial(k-1))
 ## 890.479
 exp(5)
 ## 148.4132    # Incorrect 'correction'
 6*exp(5)
 ## 890.479     # Illustrates your computation
```

A simulation in R:

```
 m = 10^5;  lambda = 5;  x = rpois(m, lambda)
 mean(x);  var(x);  mean(x^2)
 ## 4.99805    # approximates E(X) = 5
 ## 4.984376   # approximates V(X) = 5
 ## 29.96483   # approximates E(X^2) = V(X) + [E(X)]^2 = 30
```

Simulation error is somewhat greater in the last two cases.

In applications, be aware that even though $E(X) = V(X)$ numerically,
the units are different.

Finally, for archival clarity:

$$\text{E}(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\,\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}= \lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} = \lambda,$$

$$\text{E}(X^2)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}=\lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=\lambda(\lambda + 1),$$

and $\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}(X^2) - \lambda^2.$ Another approach is to find $\text{E}[X(X - 1)].$